# What is the benefit of using SimpleIoC in MVVMLight?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

This is a code segment from default template of MVVMLight (`ViewModelLocator.cs`). I have removed some parts for simplicity.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is my own version of it without using `SimpleIoC` and it is working the **same** as the first version (at least in my own observation).

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator() { }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            if(ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
               return new MainViewModel(new DesignDataService());
            else
               return new MainViewModel(new DataService());
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the second version is **easier to understand** and obviously shorter. Of course, in the first example, only one instance of MainViewModel is created(it is called the singleton pattern right?) but I think we can still achieve it without using the `SimpleIoC` class. My question is what is the benefit of *"registering"* a class/object using the `SimpleIoc` class? Please explain it to me.

Comment: 5th SOLID priciple.

Comment: @KarolisKajėnas not sure what your point is. Both examples show dependency injection, and the question is tagged as such.

Comment: @KarolisKajėnas: I will read about it. This is the first time I heard about that principle.

Comment: @Charles: My question is the use of SimpleIoC class. I want to know more about it's feature. But it seems that it is more about principle rather than feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are examples of dependency injection, but one uses a container and one is explicit; sometimes referred to as 'Poor Man's DI' or 'Pure DI'.

I'd probably agree that in this trivial example, the explicit way is less complex and is probably what I'd chose.

You might find [Mark Seeman's blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) on when to use a DI container useful.